# Auto Layout madness

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm building an app targeted (for the moment, at least) at the several sizes of recent iPhones in portrait only (no iPad yet) and have pulled out most of my hair over Auto Layout constraints. I've watched several tutorials, read several more, and yet seem unable to get the interface on the device or simulator to look the way I lay it out in the storyboard:

[image]

The tutorials, necessarily, lay out something like a couple of buttons, pinned to the corners. I can do that, no problem. But as you can see in the screenshot, I've got five UIButtons, three `UITextFields`, three `UILabels` and one `UIImageview`, which last needs to remain centered and maintain a particular aspect ratio regardless of device.

Every time I seem to have things arranged properly, the next added constraint blows the whole thing out of the water. My experience at this point suggests that it's necessary to have a strategy (which item to constrain first, which constraints to apply first, and so on) to prevent the apparent conflicts causing my problem.

Can someone please suggest a rational approach to applying constraints in this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but you are just basically groaning, not asking a real question. Yes, Auto Layout can be tricky, but it is perfectly rational and learnable - and you should learn it before you use it. - Also, please note that you are doing something quite dangerous: you are designing your interface in w:Compact h:Regular. Don't. Design in w:Any h:Any, and use one of the size classes only to express conditional _exceptions_ to the overall design.

Comment: It's constraint based. That does mean you sort of need to have a logical approach to adding the elements *or* be satisfied with ugly intermediate results until you get them all laid out and constrained properly. Adding an element likely adds additional constraints by guessing by the way you dropped it.

Comment: I usually keep it simple and just center objects horizontally and pin them vertically first, along with setting width and height constraints, then any additional items that need special constraints can be done last. Setting size classes after setting the main (any/any) constraints can make things much easier as well, but I think auto layout is one of those things that usually needs to be learned by doing.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils No, only Xcode 4 did that. Xcode 6 does not add any constraints automatically.

Comment: @matt--Thanks very much for the good tip on the choice of Any:Any! I want to defend my question as being quite real, and helpful to others. Your acknowledgment that Auto Layout is tricky, I think, qualifies a question about strategy in implementing it as a real question. Does your comment about "learning it before using it" mean that I should immerse myself in only reading about it before ever actually trying it? That's not an approach that works for me. I learn by doing, as suggested by Jordan Johnson, and by asking questions along the way. Thanks again!

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils--Thanks for the validation of my concern!

Comment: Thanks, @JordanJohnson for the outline of your strategy!

Comment: try this one, uncheck select story board vc , uncheck auto layout, uncheck use size class, then check user size class it will automatically ask to add suggested constrains. it will add 90% of constrains

Comment: Thanks, @TejasArdeshna! Very helpful for starting from a rational starting point. :)